# Mi Router no funciona con webpack2

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Al pasar mi codigo a ES6 usando webpack2 me da este error:

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `Routes`.

mi index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Routes from './Routes.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<Routes/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

mi Routes.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'react-router';
import Route from 'react-router';
import Redirect from 'react-router';
import browserHistory from 'react-router';
import Base from './base/base.jsx';
import ProductsList from './products/app.jsx';
import Login from './authenticate/login.jsx';


export default class Routes extends React.Component {

render(){
    return(
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
          <Redirect from="/" to="listado"/>
            <Route path="/" component={Base}>
              <Route path="listado" component={ProductsList}/>
              <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
             </Route>
       </Router>
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no es webpack, estas importando mal los métodos de reactrouter
 Inténtalo así

```
Import {Router, Route} from 'react-router'
```

Comment: me da el mismo erro mas este otro error: Warning: [react-router] `Router` no longer defaults the history prop to hash history. Please use the `hashHistory` singleton instead.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createRouteFromReactElement' of undefined(…)

Comment: el error que tenia esta en las impotaciones, se debe de hacer uso de las llaves. Gracias..

Answer (score 1):

Si estás usando una versión superior de React, tendras que usar

```js
Import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
```

y para el Router

```js
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <div>
    <Redirect from="/" to="listado"/>
    <Route path="/" component={Base}>
    <Route path="listado" component={ProductsList}/>
    <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
    </Route>
  </div>
</Router>
```

ojo que el "div" es importante, ya que el objeto Router solo puede tener un elemento hijo

[Acá un ejemplo más completo](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic)

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo importarlo asi

```js
import { createHistory } from 'history'
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, IndexRedirect, Redirect, useRouterHistory} from 'react-router';

const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
  basename: '/'
})

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);
```